# How to program if conditionals, and when does one approach become better than the other

Tags: java, if-statement

I am wondering, mostly as an industry standard approach, or as a explicitly best practice approach how would one usually program if conditionals.

I find myself using the first approach below very often, never truly had a problem with it. But I'm still wondering when should either be used.

*This is just an example to illustrate what I mean, it shouldn't be taken as the normal complexity of the comparisons usually utilized.*

**Example**

```
public class Validation {
   int x = 5,
       y = 10,
       z = 100,
       a = 1;

    public void compare() {
        if (x < y) {
            // Do Something
            if (y < z) {
                // Do Something
                if (z < a) {
                    System.out.println("Whatever");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void alternate() {
        if (compareNumbers(x, y)) {
            // Do something
            if (compareNumbers(y, z)) {
                // Do something
                if (compareNumbers(z, a)) {
                    System.out.println("Whatever");
                }

            }
        }
    }

    public boolean compareNumbers(int a, int b) {
        return a < b;
    }
}
```

Which one of those would be better practice? This being a super simple example, imagining you would normally use more complex validations.

And if 'alternate' is better, how many times would the comparison method/function have to be called for it to be better?

I am sorry if this belongs in StackExchange, I wasn't very sure of which one to post it in.

To narrow the scope to StackOverflow lets say this question applies exclusively to Java. Although a general programming view/response would be appreciated.

Comment: Three levels of branching is very deep and adds a lot of hard to test complexity. But there is no general rule when this is too much or not. Also nesting statements should only be done if needed. I do for example prepare guard conditions in most cases (early return).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no "industry standards" for this kind of thing.  For good reason.

As far as whether `a < b` is better that `compareNumbers(a, b)` ... the answer depends on the actual context.

In your example, most people would agree that `a < b` is better<sup>1</sup>. But this is an artificial example, and the answer could be different for other (more realistic) examples.

The same goes for all sorts of other questions about the best way to express algorithms, etc in code.  It is rare for questions like this to have a single objectively correct answer.  It is typically a matter of opinion ... and the context really matters.

---

But the bottom line is that the only real "industry standard" here is:

> Use your professional knowledge, skills and judgement.

... and that means things like:

- thinking about each particular problem and finding an appropriate (justifiable) solution,
- considering coding effort, readability<sup>2</sup>, reliability, maintainability for your solution,
- considering the economics of the situation; i.e. there is a trade-off between time spent "polishing" your code and time spent doing other things like implementing functionality, testing, writing documentation, meeting deadlines.

---

<sup>1 - If I have to scroll down a couple of pages to check what `compareNumbers` is doing, this is an impediment ... compared with an inline comparison using `<`.  Now if there was some deeper semantic behind the comparison, then method abstraction could be a good thing, especially if there were comments in the method that explained the semantics.  But in this example, `compareNumbers(a, b)` is *less semantically meaningful* than `a < b`.</sup>

<sup>2 - Another answer states (without supporting evidence) that abstracting code to methods improves readability.  This is a gross over-simplification, and often it is demonstrably false.  It is important technique ... but not always the right one.</sup>

Comment: Specifically about the point: "considering coding effort, **readability**, reliability, maintainability for your solution" How do you feel either method affects readability in particular.

Comment: 1) That is a matter of opinion.  2) In this example it makes it worse (IMO). In other examples it makes it better. 3) You can't infer general rules about it, and attempting to do so is ... misguided.

Comment: Thank you, I was fishing for this answer. I'm gonna let the question sit for 24 hours, but (so far) I would definitely give you the best answer. Thanks for taking the time to answer it.

Answer (score 4):

Extracting code to methods has several advantages:

1. It makes the code readable
2. It allows for easily changing the implementation of the method
3. It allows for unit testing of this specific method

If all your method does is to apply the `<` operator to the two arguments, I'd say none of the three reasons above apply, and that you're over-complicating things.
Just use the `<` method, and refactor your code once you need to apply a test with some more "meat" to it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I believed this was obviously an example that didn't dwell too much in terms of the actual complexity of the example, and just illustrated what I meant. I'll edit it to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2):

From my personal experience I would use the original compare if I know the conditions are always going to stay the same, however I would use the alternate if there were even the slightest chance of needing to change the conditions. That way I wouldn't have to go back and replace every single condition individually.

Answer (score 2):

To build upon breaking out the methods, I know your example is just that, a quick example, but rather than focus on the evaluation I would focus on the task and organize the code like this:

```
     public void someMethodThatCares(int x, int y, int z, int a)
     {
         taskXY(x, y);
     }

     public void taskXY(int x, int y)
     {
         if (x < y)
         {

             taskYZ(y, z);
         }

     }

     public void taskYZ(int y, int z)
     {
         if (y < z)
         {

             taskZA(z, a);
         }
     }

     public void taskZA(int z, int a)
     {
         if (z < a)
         {

         }
     }
```

Now you can build your dependencies as you need them, test each piece of functionality independently, maintain the logic in a clean fashion, and reuse it as needed.

Comment: Interesting approach.

Comment: It is situational like everyone else is saying...  If your logic deems that every type taskYZ is called, if y < z then taskZA has to be done then it makes sense.  But there are a million variations where it wouldn't too :)  Heck, you could end up with something that may or may not need post-processing and then accepts the y/z/function or y/z/callback class to allow you to inject behavior too :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I focus on the **complexity of the code** and the **importance of that logic in my project**. therefore, I might use all alternatives in the same class or even in the same method.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest reading [Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201634988) by the Gang of Four for more information on how to decide.  For every problem the approach would be different.  For example if you needed to write multiple programs that individually checked each variable, the first program doing a less than check, the second doing a greater than check, the third doing a equals check it may make sense to use the Strategy Design Pattern for each of these cases to prevent the need to create multiple programs and using a Factory creator to decide which Strategy to use.  The factory pattern could decide which one to use at run time based on user input or some other method.